# static non-inline functions causing clang to emit Wunneeded-internal-declaration warnings

Tags: c++, function, static, header, clang

I have a header file that has a number of static functions that wrap things.

```
namespace jhelper {
static void  __attribute__((noinline)) writerKey(rapidjson_writer * writer, const char * key)
{ writer->Key(key); }
}
```

Why? Because `writer->Key()` causes a load of asm to be generated. `writerKey` is used in templated functions and if `writer->Key()` (and similar functions) are not wrapped the size of my executable blows up by several megabytes.

gcc handles this well, but clang likes to spam the following warning:

```
jsonVisitor.hpp:368:41: warning: 'static' function 'writerKey' declared in header file should be declared 'static inline' [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
```

I very explicitly do not want this inlined. I am not concerned about duplicate copies of static functions existing in separate compilation units as I am using an amalgamated build for releases. How do I suppress this warning? Cheers!

Comment: Does `static inline void  __attribute__((noinline)) writerKey(/*..*/)` solve your issue, as `inline` is now unrelated to inlining.

Comment: or unnamed namespace instead of `static`?

Comment: I can confirm that an anonymous namespace does not have any effect - the warning is still emitted. I'll put the `inline`in and look at the asm and see what happens

Comment: After some fun with objdump and otool, I can confirm that `static inline void __attribute__((noinline))` does NOT inline the function with `clang -O3`, or with `g++ -O3`. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: When you have warning issues, you should post the version of the compiler you are using and the set of compiler flags.  I tried to reproduce this with clang9 and -Wall -Weverything and there is no warning generated.

Comment: @Jody Hagins
Cheers, I'll keep that in mind in the future. I'm using `-Wall`, clang 9.0.1 and cross compiling Linux -> Mac.
Full compiler flags: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000 -c -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -DREL=1 -fverbose-asm -g   -fmax-errors=5 -fno-rtti`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline` is now unrelated to inlining (and was mainly just an hint).

As you add attribute to avoid inlining, you should not have inlining.

you might do

```cpp
static inline void __attribute__((noinline))
writerKey(rapidjson_writer* writer, const char* key)
{
    writer->Key(key);
}
```